# Create simple SOAP to File communication

Tags: web-services, soap, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm new in WSO2 and I want create simple communication between client (e.g. SOAP UI) and server (e.g. Axis2) by WSO2-ESB (SOAP to File scenario). 
I'm total beginner and I don't know, how to start. 
Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not start by running a few samples?

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Samples